# How to copy R's print(x, digits = n) in Python?

Tags: python

In R `print(x, digits=n)` does something a little complicated.

It always shows all the digits to the left of the decimal point and then, if there are any digits to the right it rounds the whole number so that at most `n` digits are shown.

Examples:

```
print(2,digits=2)
2
print(23,digits=2)
23
print(23.12,digits=2)
23
print(2.12,digits=2)
2.1
print(0.126,digits=2)
0.13
print(23236.12,digits=6)
23236.1
print(123,digits=2)
123
```

How would you do that in Python?

You can try these examples online at https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: What would be `print(123,digits=2)`?

Comment: @buran It would print `123`. You always get all the digits before the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an actual solution to the problem, although it requires some string operations, it should work

```
def my_round(value, digits):
    non_dec = str(value).split('.')[0]
    non_dec_len = len(non_dec) if non_dec != '0' else 0
    return round(value, digits - non_dec_len if digits > non_dec_len else None)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer for a=0.126 and dig=2. It should be 0.13.

Comment: Are you sure? It prints `0.1` for me. For `0.126` and `3` in your examples it prints `0.13` like you requested. Was this not the intended solution, or did you produce something different? EDIT: I see you edited the question, so the function should bypass 0 as only integer in the input?

Comment: Try it at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ . That is try print(0.126, digits=2). R doesn't seem to count 0 as a digit when it is the only digit to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: I modified the script to include the '0' rule. There's too many conditionals to make a pretty one-liner so just included the function.

Comment: To be honest the one liner wasn't particularly pythonic, for the sake of maintainable code your function is a lot nicer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built-in for this, so you have to write some code, for example:

```
def nd(n, ndigits):
    s = str(int(n))
    ndigits -= len(s)
    if ndigits <= 0:
        return s
    return '{:.{}f}'.format(n, ndigits)


print(nd(1.23456, ndigits=5)) # 1.2346
print(nd(12.3456, ndigits=5)) # 12.346
print(nd(123.456, ndigits=5)) # 123.46
print(nd(1234.56, ndigits=5)) # 1234.6
print(nd(12345.6, ndigits=5)) # 12345
print(nd(123456., ndigits=5)) # 123456
```

If you need this often, you can create a custom formatter with a new specifier.

Comment: nd(2, 2) gives `2.0` but it should be `2`

Comment: @graffe: add `..rstrip('.0')` after `.format(...)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [round() function](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round):

```
print(round(23.15647, 2))
> 23.16
```

Comment: How would that work with print(23236.12,digits=6) ?

Comment: Well, it is rounding mathematically, so you'll get 23236.12

Comment: Your answer isn't correct, if you look at the examples, `23.12` to 2 digits should be `23`.